# How can I remove a software from pending updates list from Pop!_Shop?

Tags: package-management, pop-os

How can I remove a software package from the pending updates list in Pop!_Shop?

[image: Screenshot]

Because if I try to install it, it does nothing but cause more problems for other software and my drivers are working perfectly fine without it. Why I want to remove it is because Pop!_Shop keeps sending notifications that an update is pending.

Is there any way by using terminal or something I can remove it from the updates list?